# GWT SuggestBox not returning the correct value on ValueChangeHandler

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT SuggestBox. When I select an item I want to get the item selected from the database. My code is:

```
suggestionBoxScoutNumber.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
            public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
                if (suggestionBoxScoutNumber.getText().length() != 0) {
                    //Look for Youth Member and display details if found 
                    // and error message if not found.
                    suggestionBoxScoutNumber.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
                    Window.alert("suggestionBoxScoutNumber.getText() = " + suggestionBoxScoutNumber.getText());
                    AsyncCallback<YthMmbrSectDtls> callback = new GetYMHandler<YthMmbrSectDtls>(EditYouthMemberView.this);
                    rpc.getYouthMemberSection(accountId, null, null, suggestionBoxScoutNumber.getText(), callback);
                }else{
                    suggestionBoxScoutNumber.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
                }
            }
        });
```

When I enter "1" the values "123" and "912234" are displayed. I select "123" and the "Window.alert" displays "1" instead of "123" and, therefore, the value I selected is not fond in the database.

Comment: Move `suggestionBoxScoutNumber.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");` out of the "if" statement or even out of the ValueChangeHandler. It's possible you don't need it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getValue()`, not `getText()`.

Comment: Hi Andrei, Thank you for your suggestion; however, the same result - "1" returned.

Comment: What do you see in `event.getValue()`?

Comment: Hi Andrei, I see '1'. It should be '123'.

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else - not in the code that you posted.

Comment: Hi Andrei, when I change the value I expect to get the new value '123' to get the record from the database. However, the value '1' is being returned which can not be found in the database. Why is the code I posted not returning the correct value to do the database search on please?

Comment: If `getValue` returns "1", it means you pass `1` as a value, not `123`. There is a problem somewhere outside of this code. Show more code for your suggestion box, including its oracle.

Comment: OK, lets start at the beginning. I enter "1", "123" and "912345" appear in the drop down list. I select "123" and the "Window.alert" displays "1". I expect "123" to be displayed by the "Window.alert".

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over this question, just for reference if anybody out there still has to develop GWT (as I do), use `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox.addSelectionHandler(SelectionHandler<Suggestion>)` for the `SelectionChangeEvent`.
Use `ValueChangeEvent` only if you want to allow your users to enter a value and leave the box without making a selection.